# How to hang an event on an element in the sandboxed iframe from one domain?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have iframe on my page, the domain is common.

```
<iframe id = "page" src = "/" sandbox = "allow-same-origin"> </iframe>
```

I'm trying to hang an event

```
document.getElementById ("page"). onload = function () {
editor = this.contentWindow.document; 
editor.addEventListener ("contextmenu", function (e) {
// here the event code
});
}
```

In firefox, the event is triggered, in chrome - not (Blocked script execution in '' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.). Allow-scripts I can not attach. I need to disable scripts in the iframe.

Comment: Why not just set "allow-scripts" on the iframe?

Comment: `Allow-scripts I can not attach. I need to disable scripts in the iframe.` So you want to prevent scripts from running in all browsers?

Comment: I want to disable only iframe scripts, not parent document scripts in firefox and chrome

Comment: That's the default behavior of the sandbox tag. If it doesn't work in Firefox then it's either a bug or they have different defaults.